# How to look for an entity's self referenced entity in my Doctrine search?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

When looking at the User entity, you can see its a manytomany self referencing relation. A user has many friends who are users themselves. How do I make this exact same search in within a user's friends? (in this query, I'm only looking for users who fill those conditions, but I would like to perform it in a $user friends)

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select( 'USER', '' )
    ->from( 'Entity\User',  'USER' )
    ->innerJoin( 'USER.eventNotified' )
    ->where( 
        $qb->expr()->andX(
            $qb->expr()->gt( 'USER.latitude', ':minLat' ),
            $qb->expr()->lt( 'USER.latitude', ':maxLat' ),
            $qb->expr()->gt( 'USER.longitude', ':minLng' ),
            $qb->expr()->lt( 'USER.longitude', ':maxLng' ),
            $qb->expr()->eq( 'USER.available', 1 )
        )
    );
```

Here is the User entity (only properties for clarity):

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false, unique=true)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fb_id", type="bigint", nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $fb_id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=100, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $first_name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=100, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $last_name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="notation", type="integer", nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $notation;

    /**
     * Bidirectional - Many users have Many favorite comments (OWNING SIDE)
     *
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Category", inversedBy="userInterests")
     */
    private $interests;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity\User", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="friends",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     **/
    private $friends;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Request", mappedBy="user", cascade={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $requests;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Request", mappedBy="friend", cascade={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $notifications;

    /**
     * Bidirectional - Many users have notified they want to go to different events (OWNING SIDE)
     *
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Event", inversedBy="userNotified", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $eventNotified;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="age", type="integer", length=3, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $age;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="picture", type="string", length=300, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $picture;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="genre", type="string", length=10, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $genre;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isregistered", type="boolean", length=1, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $registered;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="latitude", type="decimal", length=64, precision=25, scale=20, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $latitude;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="longitude", type="decimal", length=64, precision=25, scale=20, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $longitude;

    /**
     * @var \Entity\Security_Key
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Entity\Security_Key", cascade={"persist","remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="private_key_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     * })
     */
    private $private_key;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isavailable", type="boolean", length=1, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $available = 0;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->friends = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional conditions to a join, by using the `WITH` keyword.

```
$qb->select( 'USER' )
   ->from( 'Entity\User',  'USER' )
   ->where( 'USER.id = :userId' )
   ->leftJoin('USER.friends', 'f', 'WITH', $qb->expr()->andX(
        $qb->expr()->gt( 'f.latitude', ':minLat' ),
        $qb->expr()->lt( 'f.latitude', ':maxLat' ),
        $qb->expr()->gt( 'f.longitude', ':minLng' ),
        $qb->expr()->lt( 'f.longitude', ':maxLng' ),
        $qb->expr()->eq( 'f.available', 1 )
       )
   )
```

**Edited to show where to put the userId.**

Comment: thank you, where do I specify the user ID ? Because its one user friends, so I was expecting to pass the user ID somewhere in order to say " Among the friends of this User, look at who is filling those conditinos"

Comment: Use it with a **leftJoin** instead of an **innerJoin**. Using the last one would discard the user if it has no friends, or has friends but they don't match the specified parameters. When building a join with DQL, you don't need to specify the key field that links both entities, it's done via their annotations. That's the join which links the user with its friends, don't worry about setting user id somewhere.

Comment: `WITH` basically means: Join the table on the id, specified in the annotations, *AND* use the given conditions. You can also use the `ON` keyword to explicitly describe the join column. For example `$qb->leftJoin('U.adresses', 'a', 'ON', 'U.id = a.user')`.But since you use manyToMany, you don't have an php entity for your join column, so letting doctrine do the join is easier here.